# Android - Check State of Toggle Button when app is loaded

Tags: javascript, android

I have implemented a toggle switch in my app as follows:

```
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    //some shell command
                }
                else {
                    //some shell command
                }

            }
        });
```

The toggle is working but the app is unable to "read" the current state when it is loaded... and as such always shows the button to be "off" even though it has been triggered on before. I need a way for the button to check for a value on the kernel and reflect the state based on that.

I tried this but it does not work atm:

```
//Switch check
List<String> stdout = Shell.SU.run("cat " + Files.DT2W_PATH);
for (String s : stdout) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(s) == 0)
        continue;
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);

}
```

I just need it to read a file's value on the sd card... if the value is 0 then show the button as off... if its 1 then show it as on
Please advise...

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state of toggle button inside `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` in shared preferences. And whenever you load the activity for the second time you can use that shared preferences value inside `oncreate()` method to set the state of toggle button.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a sample code / example please?

Answer (score 0):

Put this after the setOnCheckedChangedListener():

```
if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
    // Do something
} else{
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your toggle is always off as you are not storing its state when it is triggered and turned on but when you left the app its state is lost and its off by default save the state in sharedprefrences or wherever you prefer and when your application start check that previously it was on or off and assign it according to that

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example (code wise?) thank you